# azure - How to connect to socket server program running on virtual machine

Tags: sockets, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a socket based game server running on a virtual machine in Azure.
And Azure provides IP(public) and port(public) which is used for remote control.

I tried to connect to the server program with the IP and port. The client socket is connected but apparently not to the server program. client does not receive any and the server program told me there was nothing.

How do I connect to a server program running on Azure's virtual machine?

(the server program is a console project made by Visual Studio.)

Comment: Did you map your inbound ports to VM ports, either via inbound security rules (ARM-based) or endpoints (classic)?